# Issue with selecting items using regex

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I have text separated by white spaces and a search range of more than 1000 words.

Approximately 70% of the words are following this pattern `foo-bar-...-N`, where N is unknown value for counter for words written between this sign: "-". After each word(between each word) there is a blank space.

What I need is for the script to  `select` everything after the `foo-bar` up until the blank space.

I know how to select whole thing, but not how to get solution for my issue.

Here is some example for my idea:

> foo-bar foo-bar-thing foo-bar-stuff-my-gosh ... foo-bar-for-educational-purposes

And regex should select them like so:

> [foo-bar] [foo-bar]-thing [foo-bar]-stuff-my-gosh ... [foo-bar]-for-educational-purposes

Comment: So what is your desired outcome? to replace the `foo-bar` text? or insert the word assigned to the N?

Comment: I will update my question.

Comment: Done. The thing is - I should select everything that is coming after [foo-bar] in these words.

Comment: Use the pattern `(foo-bar)(\S*)`

Comment: The problem is that I need to select everything that comes after [foo-bar], but not [foo-bar] itself.
So if I have `foo-bar-list-elements` then regex should select only `-list-elements`

Comment: I'm thinking about using `sed`. It is more suitable for my issue right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a the regex to fetch a phrase and extract a substring from it.
To do that you need a group.

So here is the code you want :

```
foo-bar([\w-]*)
```

There is a space at the end don't forget it. You need to set the **global flag** as you can see in the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nO9lK2/1). And your string has to end with a space if you want to match the last one. If it's multiline don't forget the multiline flag too.